# Extra set of quotes with template variable replacement

Tags: python, django, forms

I wrote this `get_context_data` method for an update view:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyAccountEdit, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context.update({
        'form_title': 'Edit My Account',
        'form_attributes': 'method="post"',
        'form_button_label': 'Save'
    })
    return context
```

So I create/update three context variables. However, when I view this in a browser, the form appears like this:

```
<form method=""post"">
```

Because of the additional quotes, the form uses `get`, rather than `post`, since it interprets that line as an empty string after `method=`. After I changed this line in my code:

```
'form_attributes': 'method="post"',
```

to this:

```
'form_attributes': 'method=post',
```

It appears to fix the HTML to how I would expect it to render:

```
<form method="post">
```

So, the question: why does the template tag insertion work this way? What am I misunderstanding? I also tried escaping the quotes and using double-quotes on the outside.

Here is the relevant part of my template:

```
<form {{ form_attributes }}>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button class="button-primary" type="submit">{{ form_button_label }}</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a trivial mistake, but hopefully someone in the future makes it and searches Stack Overflow for it.

The problem was that I should use the `safe` filter to ensure the replacement happens as I originally expected it to.

Working template section:

```
<form {{ form_attributes|safe }}>
```

That results in the output I expect:

```
<form method="post">
```